# PHP 5.4.7 and Apache 2.2 Trouble under Windows XP

Tags: apache-2.2, php5

I'm trying to setup a test enviroment on a virtual machine running Windows XP Home (totally updated), with Apache 2.2 and PHP 5.4.7.

I can load the PHP 5 module inside httpd.conf and if I don't rename php.ini-DEVELOPMENT (or -PRODUCTION) file to php.ini, the engine works fine.

This basic configuration doesn't have MySQL module loaded, so I have to rename rename the .ini-DEVELOPMENT into .ini and edit as follows:

```
; Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
; http://php.net/extension-dir
; extension_dir = "./"
; On windows:
extension_dir = "C:/php/ext/"
...
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

Restart Apache with no problems and... all I can get is a blank page. Where can I see some error or do you know where is the trouble?

Tell me if I need to post something else to give you more details.

Answer (score 0):

To figure out what is problem search for [error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) and [display_errors](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) config directives in your **php.ini** file.

```
error_reporting  =  E_ALL

; Print out errors (as a part of the output).  For production web sites,
; you're strongly encouraged to turn this feature off, and use error logging
; instead (see below).  Keeping display_errors enabled on a production web site
; may reveal security information to end users, such as file paths on your Web
; server, your database schema or other information.
display_errors = On

; Even when display_errors is on, errors that occur during PHP's startup
; sequence are not displayed.  It's strongly recommended to keep
; display_startup_errors off, except for when debugging.
display_startup_errors = On


; Log errors into a log file (server-specific log, stderr, or error_log (below))
; As stated above, you're strongly advised to use error logging in place of
; error displaying on production web sites.
log_errors = On
```

Also please check apache log files.